# AdMob Banner Not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I am trying to programatically create a banner ad using the following code:

```
+ (void)createBanner:(UIViewController *)sender
{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        bannerHeight = 50;
    }
    else
    {
        bannerHeight = 90;
    }

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    // request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceNumberIDNumber", @"Simulator"];
    // request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

    bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
    bannerView.adUnitID = @"MY ID"; // I have replaced my AdMob ID for posting this question with "MY ID"; usually the "ca-app-pub-xxxxx.." ID is in this line
    bannerView.rootViewController = (id)self;
    bannerView.delegate = (id<GADBannerViewDelegate>)self;

    senderView = sender.view;

    bannerRect = [bannerView bounds];

    bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight);

    [bannerView loadRequest:request];

    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:senderView.frame];

    bannerContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, senderView.frame.size.height, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight)];

    for (id object in sender.view.subviews) { 
        [object removeFromSuperview];
        [containerView addSubview:object];
    }

    [senderView addSubview:containerView];
    [senderView addSubview:bannerContainerView];
}

+ (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, senderView.frame.size.width, senderView.frame.size.height - bannerHeight);
        bannerContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, senderView.frame.size.height - bannerHeight, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight);
        [bannerContainerView addSubview:bannerView];
    }];
}
```

This code works in one of my old apps when I run it, but when I run it in my new app, it refuses to load, whether I run it with test ads or not.

Now for a potentially significant detail: In the .h file of the `ViewController`, the interface line reads `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>`, but the view controller is embedded in a `Navigation Controller`, as shown when I load the app, which has a navigation bar at the top.

Would this be the reason the banner is not loading, and if so, how may I fix this?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recall dealing with this issue by caching the `bannerView` object in a collection.

Somewhere in code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * googleAdsCollection;

// in viewDidLoad 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.googleAdsCollection = [NSMutableArray array];
    // ... your code here ...
}
- (void)createBanner {
   // in your create banner perhaps at the end
   [self.googleAdsCollection addObject:bannerView];
   // ... your cod here ...
}

// inside the adView delegates - received, failed, what else
[self.googleAdsCollection removeObject:view]
```

Comment: The createBanner: method won't let me reference the property self.googleAdsCollection, nor will it let me reference things such as self.navigationController.view. Also, how will adding the banner to an array and removing it again help the ad be displayed? I appreciate the help, though I can't see the logic behind the fix unfortunately.